# grails getPersistentValue() value changes without saving

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using the getPersistentValue() method to determine how a property changed. However I've discovered that this method returns different values even if I have not explicitly saved the object.
Here's what I've narrowed it all the way down to...

```
trip.properties=[start:params.startmile,
        end:params.endmile, 
        satusFlag:params.statusFlag,
        description:params.description            
       ];

  // print statusFlag for checking
  log.debug(trip.getPersistentValue('statusFlag')+":"+trip.statusFlag);

  def driver=driverService.getValidDriver(params.driver,params.date);
  //the persistent value of statusFlag has changed!!!!
  log.debug(trip.getPersistentValue('statusFlag')+":"+trip.statusFlag);
```

The service call is just another criteria search to return a driver if he/she was employed at a date

```
 def driver=Drivers.createCriteria().get{
        and{
           eq('id',id);
           eq('division',division);
           le('startDate',compareDate);
           or{
               ge('endDate',compareDate);
               isNull('endDate');
           }
         }

     };
    return service
```

For some reason this query in a service forces my other objects to update their persistent values? Can someone explain why and how to avoid this?

Comment: you don't have to explicitly save to have values update. Although your query does not show any form of update going on. It maybe due to .get try .list or .read maybe ?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529503/how-to-set-default-behaviour-to-grails-criteria

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by importing the transaction annotation

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
```

and then adding

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

before the method that was being called.

However this won't work in all cases because not all service calls will be read only.